# How can I get existing bearer token without of created it in Laravel Passport on Password Grant?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Every time I POST on oauth/token it creates the new token.

But how can I get an existing before token, without creation new?

**For example:**

```
GET oauth/token?name=John&password=1234567
```

**Response:**

```
{"token": "dsfwsgehejteyrkekl"}
```

Because I need just GET token for me as user, not to recreate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like that:

```
Auth::user()->token();
```